# Why so few people to vote?

Tags: discussion

I've been discovering OpenData SE and although I kind of like the topic, my impression is that this SE is not doing great. I've been active on a few other SE sites for some time and one can really tell the difference. Apparently there's just not enough regular active members for the flow of questions ([939 visits/day and 1.7 questions/day](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-traffic)). Crucially there are [very few votes being cast](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=quarter), and this is quite bad given that the SE model relies on votes.

I understand that for the question asking if the quality is low or it looks like there was not sufficient effort or time put into asking a question it can be downvoted.

I feel like by penalizing downvotes we are discouraging people from holding answers to higher standards.

Interested to hear you guys thoughts on this

**So what I'd like to know is:**

**Why so few people vote?**

Is it because there are not enough "avid members", too much turn-over, too many questions, questions being too specialized (or not enough)...?

**What can be done about it?** (if anything) More precisely, as a modest active member, what should I prioritize?
For instance, I've seen other sites which encourage:

- [**Vote early and vote often:**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/19/vote-early-vote-often/) should I vote on questions/answers even if I don't feel very confident about the topic?
- voting to close out-of-scope/unclear questions early (and harshly) in order to force the user to clarify before (possibly) re-opening. But of course, that's not very welcoming.
- be more strict about duplicates: many beginners questions are variants of existing questions, should I vote to close as duplicate even if it's not exactly the same question?
- any other suggestion...?

Answer (score 3):

I agree that the site isn't doing well.

One weakness is that people who are referred (or questions migrated) here from other sites ask their "data request" question and then never come back. Or only come back if they get an email notification of an answer.

I think the "data request" is powerful but also a flaw when put into the context of Stack Exchange platform.

> *as a modest active member, what should I prioritize*

it's cool that are around and answering questions.

Comment: is it ok if i add my comments as edits to your answer? not really sure about etiquette here. are two answers showing better? idk.